# WordPress/Facebook Comment Count Anchor

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have recently set up a blog on WordPress. I am using a plugin called Facebook Comments to enable comments via facebook on my blog, and display the comment count at the bottom of my post previews on the main page (it's "X Komentarzy", since it's in Polish). The code that I've used for that, located in the content.php file, is:

```
<fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"></fb:comments-count> komentarzy
```

I have, however, noticed, that this is static. What I would ideally like to achieve, is that every comment count on the main page would link to the bottom of a respective (full) post, where the facebook comment section/box is. Does anyone have any idea as to how this could be achieved? I think it might have something to do with the 'anchors', but since I'm quite a beginner to WordPress I have no idea about how something like this would be set up.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to add an actual anchor to the comments count like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>#loop-nav-singlular-post"><fb:comments-count href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"></fb:comments-count> komentarzy</a>
```

I've used the id "loop-nav-singlular-post" as it is the last ID on the page so it should scroll to the very bottom of the single template, but you could add a custom anchor on the single page. and replace it in the link on the index page.